# Keep unique entries by name and by time

Tags: r

A bit of code golf I am facing and struggling quite a bit. I had a hold to a complex dataset in long format, which I need in wide for analysis. I managed to convert easily. However, there is redundancy in the dataset after the convertion because of how the data was filled. So here is a MWE with the problem I am facing:

```
id <- c("ana","ana","ana", "brad","ana","brad","brad","brad", "matt", "matt", "matt")
hour <- c(0,    0,    24,    0,     48,    24,   NA,    72,    0 ,     24,     48 )
assessment <- c("memory", "memory", "attention",  "verbal",  "attention", "memory", "attention","attention", "memory", "attention", "attention")
value <- c(0.000,NA,0.895,0.000,15.000, 3, 5, NA,2,  4,5 )

mydata<-data.frame(id, hour, assessment, value)
```

Results in:

```
> mydata
     id hour assessment  value
1   ana    0     memory  0.000
2   ana    0     memory     NA
3   ana   24  attention  0.895
4  brad    0     verbal  0.000
5   ana   48  attention 15.000
6  brad   24     memory  3.000
7  brad   NA  attention  5.000
8  brad   72  attention     NA
9  matt    0     memory  2.000
10 matt   24  attention  4.000
11 matt   48  attention  5.000
```

and after:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(i1=row_number()) %>% 
    spread(assessment, value)
```

gets to:

```
Source: local data frame [11 x 6]
Groups: id [3]

       id  hour    i1 attention memory verbal
*  <fctr> <dbl> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     ana     0     1        NA      0     NA
2     ana     0     2        NA     NA     NA
3     ana    24     3     0.895     NA     NA
4     ana    48     4    15.000     NA     NA
5    brad     0     1        NA     NA      0
6    brad    24     2        NA      3     NA
7    brad    72     4        NA     NA     NA
8    brad    NA     3     5.000     NA     NA
9    matt     0     1        NA      2     NA
10   matt    24     2     4.000     NA     NA
11   matt    48     3     5.000     NA     NA
```

Note that ana has two entries for hour 0 and memory; and brad has one entry with zero and another with missing. That missing should be considered as zero as well, that was a typing error of whoever collected the data.

The table below shows how ana's and brad's entries should be. Repetitions for the same id and hour (including NA) should be collapsed/merged (look at lines 1 and 5 below).

```
       id  hour    i1 attention memory verbal
*  <fctr> <dbl> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     ana     0     1        NA      0     NA
2     ana    24     3     0.895     NA     NA
4     ana    48     4    15.000     NA     NA
5    brad     0     1     5.000     NA      0
6    brad    24     2        NA      3     NA
7    brad    72     4        NA     NA     NA
9    matt     0     1        NA      2     NA
10   matt    24     2     4.000     NA     NA
11   matt    48     3     5.000     NA     NA
```

Question:

- How do I reduce the duplicates for each subject+hour in such a dataset, so that it will look like the previous table?

Comment: Do you want the 'hour' NA to be considered '0'?

Comment: yes, and that brad's two entries with 0 (after conversion of NAs to 0) get merged.

Comment: Can you try `mydata %>%  mutate_at(vars('hour', 'value'), funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0))) %>% arrange(id, hour, desc(value)) %>% distinct() %>% group_by(id, hour, assessment) %>% spread(assessment, value)`

Comment: Still getting `Erro: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  "hour"
*  "value"` after updating dplyr to 0.7.1

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting any error with your example data

Comment: What tidyr version are you using?

Comment: I am using 0.6.3

Comment: Same here, cant find where it is choking.

Comment: Found the problem `mydata %>%
    mutate_at(vars(hour, value), funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0))) %>%
    arrange(id, hour, desc(value)) %>%
    distinct() %>%
    group_by(id, hour, assessment) %>%
    spread(assessment, value)` it was the quotes. Please, write an answer so that I can accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `replace` the NA with 0, get the `distinct` rows and then proceed as in the OP's code

```
mydata %>%
    mutate_at(vars(hour, value), funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0))) %>% 
    arrange(id, hour, desc(value)) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    group_by(id, hour, assessment) %>%
    spread(assessment, value)
```

Comment: Thanks, your code solves the ana's problem. But is not replacing the NAs for zeroes..

Comment: @lf_araujo  Not clear about your comment.  Isn't the expected output as showed in your post

Comment: You solved the problem in line 1 of last table, but not in line 5. Note that not only Brad's NA was converted to 0, but it was also merged into brad's other hour 0 entry.

Comment: I am getting the following in last edit `Erro: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  "hour"
*  "value"`

Comment: @lf_araujo  I am using dplyr_0.7.0 and not getting that error